# What's difference netween git fetch B + git merge B VS git merge origin/B

Tags: git, merge, fetch, git-merge, git-fetch

What's the difference between git fetch B + merge B and merge origin/B?

```
$ git fetch origin develop
From [...]
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git merge develop
Already up-to-date.
$ git merge origin/develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge
...
```

In the above sequence I expect the merges to output same, but results are different. I expected the "fetch" command to retrieve the remote branch locally for it to be available for the local merge operations. After fetch is done I expected the merge from local branch to be the equal operation to the merge from the origin. Am I wrong with this expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch only downloads the commits, but does not apply them to your local copy of the branch. For the two operations to be equivalent, you'd need to merge origin/B with (local) B first. If you don't do that, local B's HEAD isn't changed, and the branch will be "behind" origin (you can verify this by running git status when you have local B checked out or by running git branch -vv).

Note that this is the same discrepancy as when you git checkout B vs git checkout origin/B.

Answer (score 0):

- `git fetch origin develop`

  Fetches the `develop` branch on the remote into your remote branch `origin/develop` (which exists locally)
- `git merge develop`

  Merges the local `develop` branch into the current branch. Assuming you have `develop` currently checked out, this will not do anything.
- `git merge origin/develop`

  Merge the local `origin/develop` branch into the current branch. `origin/develop` refers to the remote branch for `develop` in the local repository of the `origin` remote. This will merge the branch you fetched in the first step.

Comment: forgot to mention, I'm in feature/XXX branch